# I am trying to display ajax result in html but append() function displays raw html tags .

Tags: javascript, html, append

I am trying to display ajax result in html but append() function displays raw html tags .

```
 success:function(result){
      var element = document.createElement('div');
      jQuery.each(result.data , function(key,value){
          element.append('<div class="col-lg-6">'+value["name"]+'</div>')

      });
      $('.user-profile').html(element);

    }
```

Any help!

Comment: Have you checked if result is not empty? Or maybe there is no value["name"] property?

Comment: it displays raw html tags with name :)

Comment: can you add an example of the data

Answer (score 2):

You've to explicitly create every element:

```
 success:function(result){
      var element = document.createElement('div');
      jQuery.each(result.data , function(key,value){
          var divElem = document.createElement('div');
           divElem.className = 'col-lg-6';
           divElem.innerHTML = value["name"];
          element.appendChild(divElem);

      });
      $('.user-profile').html(element);

    }
```

[append](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ParentNode/append) method accepts node objects and DOMString . But, its specification has not been stabilized. It is better to use [appendChild](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild) which accepts node object.

Comment: thanks it works just fine ...could you please explain why my code does not work .

Comment: You're passing pure html string/text to append method where element is not an jquery object. You could have converted it as jquery object like so : `$(element).append('<div class="col-lg-6">'+value["name"]+'</div>')`

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried to simply add the content as html in your element ?

```
success:function(result){
    var str = '';
    jQuery.each(result.data , function(key,value){
        str += '<div class="col-lg-6">'+value["name"]+'</div>';
    });
  $('.user-profile').html(str);

}
```

Comment: i tried this and it works ... why my code does not work . what's the reason ?

Comment: @nohan You're trying to set the html value of an element to an object.  If you'd used `$('.user-profile').append(element);` it would have worked.  However, this is better as it builds all the markup and adds it with one operation, rather than performing repeated additions to the page (it's a noticeable difference).

Comment: @Archer Thanks alot

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using jQuery it could be done like :

```
success:function(result){
  var element = $('<div/>');

  jQuery.each(result.data, function(key, value){
      element.append( $('<div/>', {class: "col-lg-6",text: value["name"]}) );
  });

  $('.user-profile').html(element);
}
```

Hope this helps.